# INNER JOIN en Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Estoy migrando una consulta de Access a SQL Server, el problema es que en Access permite realizar INNER JOIN en el UPDATE

```
UPDATE (Aux_Nodos INNER JOIN Nodos_NULL_Titular ON Aux_Nodos.Necesidad = Nodos_NULL_Titular.Necesidad)
INNER JOIN Out_Arcos ON Aux_Nodos.Id_Nodo = Out_Arcos.Id_Nodo_Destino 
SET Out_Arcos.Id_Nodo_Destino = Nodos_NULL_Titular.Id_Nodo
```

En StackOverFlow en ingles vi que habia que hacer algo asi, pero me tira error

```
UPDATE dbo.Aux_Nodos SET Out_Arcos.Id_Nodo_Destino = Nodos_NULL_Titular.Id_Nodo
FROM Aux_Nodos 
INNER JOIN Nodos_NULL_Titular ON Aux_Nodos.Necesidad = Nodos_NULL_Titular.Necesidad
INNER JOIN Out_Arcos ON Aux_Nodos.Id_Nodo = Out_Arcos.Id_Nodo_Destino
```

El error que aparece es "The multi-part identifier "dbo.Out_Arcos.Id_Nodo_Destino" could not be bound.", no lo reconoce en el SET, obviamente esa tabla y columna existen.

Comment: pero la tabla que quieres actualizar realmente es `Out_Arcos`, correcto?

Comment: @Lamak Tengo que migrar eso que esta hecho así, en realidad analizándolo lo que modifica es Out_Arcos, no se porque en el UPDATE esta Aux_Nodos

Comment: Y sólo para estar seguro, le quieres cambiar el `Id_Nodo_Destino`?. Pregunto porque me parece extraño que se lo quieras cambiar, cuando lo estás usando para hacer el cruce de las filas a actualizar. Es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: @Lamak Si, lo que cambian en la query original es Out_Arcos.Id_Nodo_Destino

Answer (score 13, accepted):

De acuerdo a tus comentarios, lo que necesitas hacer en SQL Server es:

```
UPDATE OA
SET OA.Id_Nodo_Destino = NN.Id_Nodo
FROM Out_Arcos OA
INNER JOIN Aux_Nodos AN
    ON OA.Id_Nodo_Destino = AN.Id_Nodo
INNER JOIN Nodos_NULL_Titular NN
    ON AN.Necesidad = NN.Necesidad;
```

Esta es la sintaxis correcta para `UPDATE` con `JOIN` en SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal espero esta ayuda te sirva. en momentos he tenido que realizar actualizaciones a mas de una tabla y mi única ayuda es saber sus llaves foráneas.

te paso un ejemplo algo no tan elegante pero funcional sin la necesidad de hacer inner joins para darle mas eficiencia puedes meterlo todo en un SP

```
UPDATE tabla1,tabla2,tablaN
 SET tabla1.campo ='valor que quieres guardar',
     tabla2.campo ='valor que quieres guardar',
     tablaN.campo ='valor que quieres guardar'
WHERE tabla1.id = id AND tabla2.id = id AND tablaN.id =id
```

repito la verdad no es una solucion elegante pero es fucional y bueno puedes colocarlo en un SP y con ello hacer algo bastante efectivo

lo mejor de todo es que no usas inner joins y eso te hace de alguna manera darle tu complejidad